# SQL percent of previous total

Tags: mysql, sql

We have an ORDERS table with three columns: CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID and PRODUCTS_ID.  Sample data:

```
CUSTOMER_ID ORDER_ID    PRODUCT_ID  ORDER_DAY
C1          O1          P1          1-Jan-15
C1          O1          P2          1-Jan-15
C1          O1          P3          1-Jan-15

C2          O2          P6          2-Jan-15
C2          O2          P1          2-Jan-15
C2          O2          P3          2-Jan-15

C1          O3          P1          3-Jan-15
C1          O3          P3          3-Jan-15
C1          O3          P6          3-Jan-15
C1          O3          P7          3-Jan-15
```

Can you write a query to have the following output?

```
ORDER_ID    #PRODUCTS   #PRODUCTS_IN_PAST   %PRODUCTS_IN_PAST
O1          3           0                   0%
O2          3           0                   0%
O3          4           2                   50%
```

Where:

```
   #PRODUCTS: total number of products purchased in the order
   #PRODUCTS_IN_PAST is the number of the products in the particular order that were purchased by the same customer in the past.
   %PRODUCTS_IN_PAST = #PRODUCTS_IN_PAST/#PRODUCTS
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? This is do-able - easier in some DBMS's than others - however, you should show your effort.

Comment: I'm a SQL newbie, so I'm stuck with this problem.  Also, I've been using some SQL procedures in SAS and Python, but the database itself isn't that important.  I would defalut to MySQL.

Comment: The database, even version of the database, may matter in proposing a solution for you as not all features/functions are available.

Comment: I would use MySQL for the database.

Comment: Have you attempted writing a query in SQL? If so, can you post it? We can help you wherever you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
select order_id, count(*) as numproducts, sum(is_previous), avg(is_previous)
from (select o.*,
             (case when o.product_id in (select o2.product_id
                                         from orders o2
                                         where o2.customer_id = o.customer_id and
                                               o2.order_date < o.order_date
                                         )
                    then 1 else 0
              end) as is_previous
      from orders o
     ) o
group by o.order_id;
```